# Rails Ajax Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am making one part of my app load via ajax and I ahve set it all up, I clikc the link which has `remote: true` set on it, the correct URL is requested but in the console I get a 500 error and the following:

> Started GET "/coasters?page=18" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-08 18:46:08
>   +0000 Processing by CoastersController#index as JS   Parameters: {"page"=>"18"}   Rendered shared/_fact-bar.html.erb (0.9ms)   Rendered
>   coasters/index.html.erb (1.5ms) Completed 500 Internal Server Error in
>   3ms
>
> NoMethodError - undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass:
>
>   app/views/shared/_fact-bar.html.erb:6:in`
>   _app_views_shared__fact_bar_html_erb__2012545158101504906_70360428754860'
>   actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in
>   render'   activesupport (3.2.12)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in`instrument'   actionpack
>   (3.2.12) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'

I'm not quite sure what part is causing the error. Any help in tracking it down?

Fact bar partial:

```
<div class="facts bar bar--white-wave">
  <div class="container--padded">
    <h1>Facts &amp; Statistics</h1>
    <ul class="fact-circle-container">
      <% circleCount = 1 %>
      <% @stats.each_with_index do |stat, i| %>
        <% if stat[:active] == 1 then %>
          <li>
            <% if stat[:link] then %>
              <a href="<%= stat[:link] %>">
            <% end %>
              <div class="fact-circle fact-circle--<%= circleCount %>" data-number="20">
                <div class="inner">
                  <span><%= stat[:value] %></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            <% if stat[:link] then %>
              </a>
            <% end %>
            <h3 class="fact-circle__title"><%= stat[:name] %></h3>
          </li>
          <% circleCount = circleCount + 1 %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us fact-bar.html.erb partial?

Looks like you may be calling each_with_index on something that isn't an Enumerable type.

Comment: You're calling `each_with_index` in your `_fact-bar` partial on something that's `nil`.

Comment: You have everything written there: file app/views/shared/_fact-bar.html.erb, line 6. You are trying to call each_with_index on variable which returns nil.

Comment: Add the fact bar partial to my OP. I don;t know why this is causing errors as that part has nothing to do with the part I am ajaxing?

Comment: need to show the controller action that sets it,  Perhaps on page 18 there are no more results?

Comment: Heres the action: https://gist.github.com/rctneil/8322458

Comment: Why do you have all the logic inside the format.html block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because you are calling `each_with_index` on `@stats`, which evaluates as `nil` in your partial.

Presumably, your AJAX action is not calling `index` with the `html` format - which is where `@stats` is being defined. As such, you'd need to refactor the code that defines `@stats` to be called from your ajax action/format as well.

Comment: Ok. Will look at that when I get back

Comment: Either put the `@stats` declaration before the `respond_to` block, or put it in a private method that can be called inside each format that will need it.

Comment: Brill. Just got it working.   I have another question with pagination but a new question is best so will do that. Thanks again!